# How to add slide effect to Bootstrap's data-toggle?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know if there is a built-in feature in Bootstrap to add slide effect to `data-toggle="collapse"`? This is what I have:

```
<div id="btn-nav">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div>Navigation</div>
</div>

<div id="target" class="target col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="area1">Nunc accumsan sem sed tortor.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it works fine but without the slide effect.

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/942yky00/).

Comment: Can you show the scripts and css about bootstrap you include on your page ?

Comment: Exactly, when you paste this in to a Bootstrap ready page, there's nothing.

Comment: @TheLittlePig - I have updated my question and added jsFiddle link.

Comment: @Christina Please see my updated question with jsFiddle. I just included css. Apart from that, it works with original Bootstrap script.

Comment: No time to answer this, but the collapse is show hide, no animation from one direction to another. The way most people do this is with toggling classes and using css to animate. The width is either the column classes or the target, not both. I cleaned this up, there was interesting use of the grid which I removed. http://jsbin.com/lowigu/

Comment: There is natively a slide effect but your css break it : with small changes : http://jsfiddle.net/942yky00/1/ , but the effect is not perfect because the height 100% I think, or maybe something else... And with setting height to Opx : http://jsfiddle.net/942yky00/2/

Comment: @TheLittlePig It's good that it can be done through Bootstrap without writing a separate jQuery. But can it be slided from right to left? Otherwise I may have to follow Christina's solution.

Comment: @Christina That's a nice solution. Thanks for that. I've noticed that using `position:fixed` instead of `absolute` in `.target` works better. Then there is no need to use `overflow-x:hidden` in `body`. `overflow-x:hidden` does not seem to be consistent across different devices that I have tested on...

Comment: Yes, I use position:fixed. You had absolute so I made it absolute.